# Grub2 does not recognise Windows 10 and won't boot it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I wanted to use Ubuntu for the first time for deep learning purposes. I made a partition and installed Ubuntu on it. For some reason, the system booted straight to Windows. But after much tweaking, I managed to boot to GRUB only to realize that Windows 10 is not an option there. I don't know much about Linux so please pardon me.

I can see the Windows data files in the file explorer in Ubuntu.

`fdisk-l` shows

[image: nvm partitions]

`update-grub` shows

[image: generates files only for Linux kernels]

`os-prober` shows no output.

I know there are many threads like this but I can't find the solution that works as of now.

I have tried editing `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` to contain this:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
   set root='{hd0,1}'
   chainloader + 1
}
```

This creates an entry, but I can't load Windows.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use text with formatting for outputs instead of Screenshots.

Comment: Is Windows fast start up off? That turns on hibernation flag and then grub will not boot it. Grub only boots working Windows. With UEFI, you then boot Windows from UEFI's boot menu. Fast start up off: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: I turned off the fast startup before starting with this. 
@Kulfy I'm sorry for the formatting issues, will keep that in mind.